# IE7 giving 403 Error when dynamically loading image

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, jquery-forms-plugin

When submitting a form using jQuery and AJAX, I am getting a 403 error on my returned HTML that contains an `IMG`tag.

Here's the code that I'm using to submit the form:

```
// Add a new personality to the quiz
    $('form#personality_editor').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

            // Submit the form with jQuery Form plugin to handle attachments
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                dataType: "json",
                resetForm: true,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // Show the loading spinner
                    $('img#personality_loader').show();
                },
                success: function(add_personality_response) {

                    // Hide the image loader
                    $('img#personality_loader').hide('fast');

                    if (add_personality_response["success"] == "true") {

                        // Create a new personality in the list of personalities
                        $('div#quiz_personalities').append(add_personality_response["personality_html"]);

                            // Add the personality to list of hidden personalities
                            AddRemovePersonality(add_personality_response["personality_id"], "add");

                            // Set the focus on to personality name
                            $('input#new_personality_name').focus();

                            // Show or hide the no personalities notice
                            ShowHideNoPersonalitiesNotice();

                            alert("Success");
                    }

                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("There was an error adding personality");
                }
            });

    });
```

Here's the full JSON response that I'm getting back from the code:

```
    {"success":"true","personality_id":191,"personality_name":"Avril Lavigne","personality_image":"191avril.jpg","personality_html":"<div class=\"personality_wrapper\" data-personality-id=\"191\"><img src=\"images\/personalities\/personality_images\/192avril.jpg\" class=\"personality_image_small\" \/><div class=\"personality_info\"><div class=\"personality_name\" title=\"Kjh\">Kjh<\/div><div class=\"personality_options\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"personality_option personality_edit\">Edit<\/a><a href=\"#\" class=\"personality_option personality_delete\">Delete<\/a><\/div><\/div><\/div>"}
```

It is the `personality_html` that I am adding to the DOM using the `.append()` function of jQuery.

This problem is occurring in Internet Explorer, because it is working in Chrome.

The image is uploading fine to my server at the location `images/personalities/personality_images/192avril.jpg`.

The response that I'm getting back from the page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /&quot;images//personalities//personality_images//192avril.jpg/&quot;
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Is it something to do with the escaped data being passed from my page?  I am using `json_encode()` before I `echo` it in response.

Here's the view from the Developer tools in IE:

[image: Developer tools IE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely trying to parse JSON to a JavaScript object twice.

Since for the `.ajaxSubmit()` call you have already designated that the response data type is JSON, jQuery will automatically parse the response into a JavaScript object for you (it would also do this if the response `Content-Type` is `application/json`, regardless of whether you had specified `dataType` or not).

This means that inside the success callback, `add_personality_response1` will already be a JavaScript object. Yet you are trying to `$.parseJSON` it a second time:

```
var add_personality_response = $.parseJSON(add_personality_response1);
```

I 'm not quite sure if removing this line will solve the problem immediately, but it's definitely how you have to start.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the response.  I have removed this extra line of code now and sadly it's still not working.

Comment: OK, I decided to change the response so that it only returned HTML, (not json) and it worked fine.  However, now I can't detect the returned `personality_id` that was returned.